# ¿Como convertir una linea de un fichero en un array sin espacios?

Tags: php, symfony

estoy tratando de leer un fichero con php y de cieta forma convertir una linea del mismo en un array sin espacios pero al convertirlo con la funcion explode los espacios consecutivos se quedan guardados en el array y nececito que mi array no contenga ningun espacio.

estos son dos ejemplos de lineas del fichero:

1544199876.987    103 10.5.16.5 TCP_MISS/200 836 POST http://ocsp.pki.goog/GTSGIAG3 yasmanyv DIRECT/216.58.192.46 application/ocsp-response

1544199874.409 768740 10.4.37.106 TCP_MISS/200 123580 CONNECT clients4.google.com:443 yanelisa DIRECT/216.58.192.46 -

y estas son las salidas que obtengo como pueden ver en la segunda no hay espacios porque en el ficero no existen los espacios concecutivos en esa linea:

```
Array

(
[0] => 1544199876.987
[1] =>
[2] =>
[3] =>
[4] => 103
[5] => 10.5.16.5
[6] => TCP_MISS/200
[7] => 836
[8] => POST
[9] => http://ocsp.pki.goog/GTSGIAG3
[10] => yasmanyv
[11] => DIRECT/216.58.192.46
[12] => application/ocsp-response
)

Array
(
[0] => 1544199874.409
[1] => 768740
[2] => 10.4.37.106
[3] => TCP_MISS/200
[4] => 123580
[5] => CONNECT
[6] => clients4.google.com:443
[7] => yanelisa
[8] => DIRECT/216.58.192.46
[9] => -
)
```

y este es el metodo con el que obtengo los array:

```
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{

    $manager=fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\sgisi-master\public\x.txt','r');
    while (!feof($manager)){
        $cadena= fgets($manager);
        $array=explode(" ", $cadena);
        print_r ($array);

    }
}
```

favor si alguien pudiese decirme como obtener los array sin los espacios o como quitarle los que me genera le estaria agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){

    $manager=fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\sgisi-master\public\x.txt','r');
    while (!feof($manager)){
        $cadena= fgets($manager);
        // eliminamos todos los espacios de mas con \s que es para buscar coincidencias con un carácter de espacio
// el + que busca caracteres seguidos 1 o mas veces luego el [] agrupa todo los espacios
// y luego lo remplazamos por un unico espacio
        $cadena = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $cadena);
        $array=explode(" ", $cadena);
        print_r ($array);

    }
}
```